# Windows 7 hibernate not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate

I have hibernate enabled, everything should work fine. When I press the hibernate, screen goes black (as expected), but after a short time the disk LED stops flashing, and computer turns off strangely fast. Then when I try to turn on the computer again, it just displays the standard

> windows didn't shutdown properly last time

so it gives me an option to start the Windows in `Normal mode` or `Safe mode`. I choose Normal mode and computer boots. But it should actually restore the previous session! Does anybody know where a problem can be? I am definitely sure it should hibernate, as there is no "Logging out" screen, just the black screen, as expected.

I have already tried recreating the hibernation file, the problem persists.

### Update

So I've updated all the drivers, and the problem still persists. Is there anything else than `clean install`/`repair`?

Comment: What is your computer model?

Comment: @KronoS: Dell Latitude XT2

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be logged, but have you checked the system event log for any updates around hibernation?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I have checked event log, but haven't found anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by Mozy backup software, as uninstalling the program probably fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your manufacturer / motherboard makers website and see if there are any updated drivers - especially if the machine was not shipped with Windows 7 as this could be a bug or a feature that requires something extra.

Also check the BIOS to make sure it is fully supported / configured as sometimes there is an option that needs to be set.

Comment: I've updated all drivers, BIOS does not have any configuration regarding hibernation/sleep. Still, the problem persists. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I would check your drivers and make sure they are all up to date as well as the system BIOS. If those all check out I would then use `powercfg.exe -energy` to check the system out as well.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee430886.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I've updated all the drivers, and even run the power check. The check seems OK, only real problems were two erroneous devices: `USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend`. But since these are USB devices, I think it shouldn't be a problem.